# How do I stop Count Vectorizer of Python Sci-kit library from doing any kind of word filtering?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Count Vectorizer implements default basic filtering of some English words like `'a'` as written in its document [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html). It simply ignores them which I do not want. Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

```
>>> count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> list = ['a for the']
>>> counts = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(list)
>>> print counts
```

The output is

```
(0, 0)  1
(0, 1)  1
```

which means that it recognized `'for'` and `'the'` (tested) but failed to recognize `'a'`. Is there any way it can recognize every possible word?

Comment: please provide some code sample like "what i need" and "what output i've" got, "which code i've executed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doc:
token_pattern : string
Regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp select tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always treated as a token separator).

default regex is:

```
token_pattern='(?u)\b\w\w+\b'
```

Just write your own regular expression you want to use.